# Overlapping divs in a flexbox column

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a MailChimp HTML email template and have the structure sorted.

I have an image that I created in illustrator that I want as the background for `midContent`. I want the lightblue part of this [background image](https://ibb.co/J74BG5f) to overlap the above image. I've tried using `z-index`, but it doesn't seem to work. Is the `flex-box` column right for this kind of task, or should I use something else?

```css
  .templateContainer{
   max-width:450px !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
  }

  #templateHeader img {
   text-align: center;
   height: 150px;
   padding: 5px 0;
  }

  #templateHeader, #postheader {
   text-align: center;
  }

  #postheader {
   height: 75px;
   background-color: #EAEAEA;
  }

  #postheader-container {
     width: 90%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 5%;
  }

  #postheader-container p {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #039FD6;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 20px 0px;
  }

  #templateBody {
   height: 495px;
  }

  .center {
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
  }

  #topContent {
   height: 225px;
   width: 100%;
  }

  #topContent img {
   width: inherit;
  }

  #midContent {
   background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/qsfyckt/Untitled-1.png");
   z-index: 1;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 100% 0%;
   width: 100%;
  }

  #midContent p {
   padding: 40px 25px 0px 25px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #bottomContent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 125px;
   margin-top: 1%;
  }

  #bottom-container {
   height: auto;
     width: 70%;
     margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
  }

  #bottom-container button {
   width: 85%;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3% 7% 0 7%;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #0B409E;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   border-radius: 8px;
   border-color: transparent;
  }

  #templateFooter {
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #ECECEC;
  }

  #footer-container {
     width: 90%;
     margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
     padding-top: 10px;
  }

  #footer-container p {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-size: 8px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000000;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  span {
   color: #0B409E;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="templateContainer">
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
        <div id="templateHeader">

      <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/ca/caec3ebc94200aabb4a2c31891100f28.png" style="width: 350px">
                                 
     <div id="postheader">
         <div id="postheader-container" class="center">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>Sed sagittis, lacus ut placerat rutrum, massa dui vulputate tortor.</p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
    <!-- // END HEADER -->

    <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
    <div id="templateBody">

     <div id="topContent" class="center">
      <img src="https://thehardtimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/mknkjnklj.jpg">
     </div>

     <div id="midContent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis, lacus ut placerat rutrum, massa dui vulputate tortor, eget interdum ex erat suscipit nibh. Nam quis lectus mattis, dictum tortor id, vestibulum quam. Morbi a ligula nibh. Etiam id diam erat. Duis elit diam, posuere a lectus et, commodo pulvinar diam.</p>
     </div>

     <div id="bottomContent">
      <div id="bottom-container">
       <button>This is a button</button>
       <button>Another button</button>
      </div>
     </div>

 </div>
    <!-- // END BODY -->


    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
    <div id="templateFooter">
     <div id="footer-container">
      <p>Pulse <span>aqui</span> si desea dejar de recibir recordatorios de revisiones a traves de este canal</p>
  </div>
    <!-- // END FOOTER -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `position:relative` with `z-index:10000` for `#midContent`

```
  position:relative;
  z-index: 10000;
```

```css
.templateContainer{
   max-width:450px !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
  }

  #templateHeader img {
   text-align: center;
   height: 150px;
   padding: 5px 0;
  }

  #templateHeader, #postheader {
   text-align: center;
  }

  #postheader {
   height: 75px;
   background-color: #EAEAEA;
  }

  #postheader-container {
     width: 90%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 5%;
  }

  #postheader-container p {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #039FD6;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 20px 0px;
  }

  #templateBody {
   height: 495px;
  }

  .center {
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
  }

  #topContent {
   height: 225px;
   width: 100%;
  }

  #topContent img {
   width: inherit;
  }

  #midContent {
   background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/qsfyckt/Untitled-1.png");
   
      position:relative;
      z-index: 10000;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 100% 0%;
   width: 100%;
  }

  #midContent p {
   padding: 40px 25px 0px 25px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #bottomContent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 125px;
   margin-top: 1%;
  }

  #bottom-container {
   height: auto;
     width: 70%;
     margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
  }

  #bottom-container button {
   width: 85%;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3% 7% 0 7%;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #0B409E;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   border-radius: 8px;
   border-color: transparent;
  }

  #templateFooter {
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #ECECEC;
  }

  #footer-container {
     width: 90%;
     margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
     padding-top: 10px;
  }

  #footer-container p {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: helvetica-light;
   font-size: 8px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000000;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  span {
   color: #0B409E;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="templateContainer">
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
        <div id="templateHeader">

      <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/ca/caec3ebc94200aabb4a2c31891100f28.png" style="width: 350px">
                                 
     <div id="postheader">
         <div id="postheader-container" class="center">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>Sed sagittis, lacus ut placerat rutrum, massa dui vulputate tortor.</p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
    <!-- // END HEADER -->

    <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
    <div id="templateBody">

     <div id="topContent" class="center">
      <img src="https://thehardtimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/mknkjnklj.jpg">
     </div>

     <div id="midContent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis, lacus ut placerat rutrum, massa dui vulputate tortor, eget interdum ex erat suscipit nibh. Nam quis lectus mattis, dictum tortor id, vestibulum quam. Morbi a ligula nibh. Etiam id diam erat. Duis elit diam, posuere a lectus et, commodo pulvinar diam.</p>
     </div>

     <div id="bottomContent">
      <div id="bottom-container">
       <button>This is a button</button>
       <button>Another button</button>
      </div>
     </div>

 </div>
    <!-- // END BODY -->


    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
    <div id="templateFooter">
     <div id="footer-container">
      <p>Pulse <span>aqui</span> si desea dejar de recibir recordatorios de revisiones a traves de este canal</p>
  </div>
    <!-- // END FOOTER -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```